# How to use Datalab cross-project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Google Cloud Datalab uses a service account instead of the individual account. My individual account has permissions for multiple projects. However, when I try to use Datalab, I run into a permissions issue.

Should I try to give the service account permissions to other projects, or is there a way to use the individual account permissions on Datalab?

Answer (score 2):

You can run Datalab locally to use a non-service account. This is described in the Datalab wiki (Getting Started) section in the Github repo.

Answer (score 2):

We just released a new version yesterday that l[ets you pick and quickly deploy](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/). The notebook server is always local to your dev machine but you can run your Python kernels (one for each notebook session) locally with user credentials or in a GCE VM with a service account to access GCP services like BigQuery, GCS etc. The latter provides code closer to data in cloud but incurs charges while you keep the VM running.

More background: VMs (AppEngine Flex or GCE) are shared resources in a project that are typically accessible to all authorized project members. Hence storing user token on a such a shared resource presents some security concerns. Whereas your dev machine (laptop, desktop, ...) is typically under your exclusive control. Hence the two design points.

Thanks.
Dinesh Kulkarni
Product Manager, Datalab & Machine Learning, GCP

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/ is the link to get started with the Datalab beta refresh.